# Sqlite Query Optimization (select * from where in AND not in order by limit offset)

Tags: sqlite

Any ideas for optimizing the following query using Sqlite3?

```
SELECT * FROM Feed 
    WHERE ActivityType IN ('PhotoActivity','CommentActivity') 
    AND UserKey NOT IN ('testUser', 'testUser2') 
    ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC 
    LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0;
```

The table will never have over 100,000 records and we expect 100 to 1 reads to writes.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Table Sql is:

```
CREATE TABLE Feed (
        FeedActivityKey TEXT PRIMARY KEY,           
        UserKey TEXT,
        AssemblyQualifiedName TEXT,
        SerializedObject BLOB,
        ActivityType TEXT,
        CorrelatedKey TEXT,
        TimeStamp INTEGER);
    CREATE INDEX Feed_ActivityTypeUserKey ON [FriendFeed] (
    [ActivityType], [UserKey] DESC);
    CREATE INDEX Feed_UserKey ON [FriendFeed] (
    [UserKey] DESC);
    CREATE INDEX Feed_TimeStamp ON [FriendFeed] (
    [TimeStamp] DESC);
```

Explain Output is:

0   Trace   0   0   0       0

1   OpenEphemeral   1   3   0   keyinfo(1,-BINARY)  0

2   Integer 20  1   0       0

3   MustBeInt   1   0   0       0

4   IfZero  1   73  0       0

5   Integer 0   2   0       0

6   MustBeInt   2   0   0       0

7   IfPos   2   9   0       0

8   Integer 0   2   0       0

9   Add 1   2   3       0

10  IfPos   1   12  0       0

11  Integer -1  3   0       0

12  String8 0   4   0   PhotoActivity   0

13  String8 0   5   0   CommentActivity 0

14  Goto    0   74  0       0

15  OpenRead    0   2   0   7   0

16  OpenRead    2   4   0   keyinfo(2,BINARY,BINARY)    0

17  If  7   25  0       0

18  Integer 1   7   0       0

19  OpenEphemeral   4   1   0   keyinfo(1,BINARY)   0

20  Null    0   9   0       0

21  MakeRecord  4   1   9   a   0

22  IdxInsert   4   9   0       0

23  MakeRecord  5   1   9   a   0

24  IdxInsert   4   9   0       0

25  Rewind  4   53  0       0

26  Column  4   0   6       0

27  IsNull  6   52  0       0

28  Affinity    6   1   0   aab 0

29  SeekGe  2   52  6   1   0

30  IdxGE   2   52  6   1   1

31  IdxRowid    2   9   0       0

32  Seek    0   9   0       0

33  Column  0   0   10      0

34  Column  2   1   11      0

35  Column  0   2   12      0

36  Column  0   3   13      0

37  Column  2   0   14      0

38  Column  0   5   15      0

39  Column  0   6   16      0

40  MakeRecord  10  7   9       0

41  Column  0   6   17      0

42  Sequence    1   18  0       0

43  Move    9   19  1       0

44  MakeRecord  17  3   8       0

45  IdxInsert   1   8   0       0

46  IfZero  3   49  0       0

47  AddImm  3   -1  0       0

48  Goto    0   51  0       0

49  Last    1   0   0       0

50  Delete  1   0   0       0

51  Next    2   30  0       0

52  Next    4   26  0       0

53  Close   0   0   0       0

54  Close   2   0   0       0

55  OpenPseudo  5   1   7       0

56  Sort    1   72  0       0

57  AddImm  2   -1  0       0

58  IfNeg   2   60  0       0

59  Goto    0   71  0       0

60  Column  1   2   9       0

61  Integer 1   8   0       0

62  Insert  5   9   8       0

63  Column  5   0   10      0

64  Column  5   1   11      0

65  Column  5   2   12      0

66  Column  5   3   13      0

67  Column  5   4   14      0

68  Column  5   5   15      0

69  Column  5   6   16      0

70  ResultRow   10  7   0       0

71  Next    1   57  0       0

72  Close   5   0   0       0

73  Halt    0   0   0       0

74  Transaction 0   0   0       0

75  VerifyCookie    0   5   0       0

76  TableLock   0   2   0   FriendFeed  0

77  Goto    0   15  0       0

Comment: I assume it's just a typo, but the DDL you gave creates a table called Feed but indexes a table called FriendFeed.  If that's really the case, you're not indexing the table you're selecting against.

Comment: What is the cardinality of (ActivityType), (UserKey), and (ActivityType, UserKey)?  Are they supported by reference tables in which you could possibly store integer IDs?

Comment: These databases will be stored per user in a system that has a lot of users.  Storing reference tables for these would result in a ton of duplicated data.  I can use an enum for activity types, but UserKey could be an unknown value in the context of this dataset.

Comment: After running Analyze I managed to get the query down to 8 ms.

Answer (score 1):

- Add columns to your select
- Normalize more the table. For example you can define `ActivityType`,`UserKey` in a different table having a numeric primary key.
- since you have 100 to 1 read to writes, issue a `SHARED` lock before select (the write process can wait a bit longer if has to)

Comment: I can probably normalize ActivityType but UserKey is impossible due to the structure of our app.  Maybe a hash code for user key would be faster instead of the current implementation?  Most of the UserKeys are GUIDS.

Comment: how long takes the query as it is? do you issue in desktop or mobile environment?

Comment: Desktop Environment.  With 100,000 rows the query takes 1019 ms

Comment: Ok. I think your issue here is the amount of data that needs to be transfered from disk to memory. Try limiting the select * to something more precise. In case if by using limited return columns satisfies you, and you need all the columns in your query, try saving data heavy columns in gzip format to reduce the data from disk to memory.

Comment: The table has 100,000 records, but im only taking the first 20 that match.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `select * from` and change it to `select [column1], [column2] from`

The reason for this is so that you ONLY return the values you need (IE: i see your table has 6 columns, but you're only returning 5 columns in your results.), and it reduces overhead since your not using a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe OR will be faster than IN?

---

**EDIT**
Check this: http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#or_opt

Comment: No that is not. the `IN` syntax is faster. (one parse only)

Comment: I need the AND syntax anyways.. I read the Optimization notes and setup my index to them... I am not familiar with the op codes and was hoping someone that knows them could help.